# Fields are not getting deleted in mysql database in jhipster microservice gateway application

Tags: jhipster

I removed an entity in jhipster microservice gateway project. All its related files got removed, but the fields are not getting deleted in mysql database.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Please describe what you tried, did you do it only on gateway or also on service?

Comment: I tried to delete a field in an entity. The corresponding field is not getting removed in database

Comment: @GaëlMarziou is there any way to delete an entity completely, rather than deleting only fields of an entity ?

Comment: OK but did did you try on both gateway AND service or ony gateway? As far as I know there's no entity delete feature, users tend to rely on git for this, it requires some discipline like committing after each entity generation but it works well.

Comment: only on service

Comment: Thanks @GaëlMarziou. Any update about my previous question ?

Comment: which question?